# Mutual Authentication using certifcates

Tags: authentication, certificates

How are digital certificates used to enable ***mutual authentication*** between two users? Suppose, at a bank, the employees are required to authenticate each other before transmitting sensitive data. How can a ***digital certificate*** be helpful in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your question is about. Don't you understand why a digital certificate can be used for authentication at all? Don't you understand why it can be used for mutual authentication (both sides have a certificate to authenticate against the peer). Don't you understand how it is done technically (i.e. that it can be done with TLS)? Please edit your question to make the focus more  clear.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how is it done technically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a party authenticates itself using certificates it essentially proves that it can make use of the private key associated with the public key in the certificate - since it assumed that the private key is secret and only known to the owner of certificate.

To prove access to the private key the authenticating party signs a challenge which is at least partly determined by the peer (to deter replay attacks). The peer then can verify the signature using the public key inside the public certificate.

Since a successful signature only proves access to the private key for a specific certificate the peer also has to verify that the certificate matches its expectations, i.e. typically that it is signed by a trusted certificate authority (CA), has a specific subject, is not expired or revoked and has the correct key usage extensions.

Within TLS typically only authentication of the server is done, the signature is part of the `ServerKeyExchange` message and is done over various data which also include the client-determined `ClientHello.random`. The client typically requires that the correct hostname matches the server certificates Subject Alternative Names (SAN) or (older and obsolete) matches the certificate subjects CN.

With mutual authentication the server also requests the client to authenticate itself. This is done using the `CertificateRequest` message. This message can also a list of CA the server is willing to accept as issuer of the client certificate so that the client application can choose the expected certificate. If a client received this `CertificateRequest` and has a matching client certificate it will send a `Certificate` message with this certificate. Additionally it will  send a `CertificateVerify` message which includes a signature created with the client certificates private key and covering all handshake messages send so far - which include the server-determined `ServerHello.random`.

How exactly the client certificate is validated and associated with a specific client is not defined but it is common that any certificate issued by a specific CA will be accepted and that the clients name or email will be extracted from the certificate subjects CN.